# How to create multiple objects in DRF ignoring errors if object already exists?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a POST endpoint that accepts a JSON payload - parses values from it, creates dictionaries from those values - then feeds those dictionaries to model serializers to create objects.

I don't believe DRF is meant for what I'm trying to do here, but it is a requirement.

My main question using the example below is this:

Currently if an instance exists, Django will throw an error about unique_constraint field error (exactly as it should).  However, since this is kind of a weird endpoint, I need those errors ignored.  So if for example a product already exists, instead of unique_constraint error, it just continues on and creates platform.

The rest of this app will require that error to be thrown, it is only in this function that I wish to ignore those errors.  Serializers are shared throughout the app so I don't really want to touch or override the Serializer in this case.

```
def job_start(request, platform_name="other", script_version="1"):

    # load in data
    json_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    jenkins_vars = jenkins_lib(json_data)

    # create dictionary of key/values required to create Product
    product_dict = {}
    product_dict['name'] = jenkins_vars.product
    product_dict['product_age'] = jenkins_vars.age

    #create object via DRF
    serializer = ProductSerializer(data.product_dict)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()    


    # create dictionary of key/values required to create Product
    platform_dict = {}
    platform_dict['name'] = jenkins_vars.platform_name
    platform_dict['platform'] = jenkins_vars.platform_id

    #create object via DRF
    serializer = PlatformSerializer(data.platform_dict)
    if serializer.is_valid():
       serializer.save()
```

Also any advice on how to better accomplish above would be appreciated.

Comment: also wondering if i need to first serialize my dictionary before feeding it to the serializer or if it will just accept a dictionary as shown?

Comment: I don't know about DRF but why not a try: exception: pass?

Comment: If job_start is a view or is being called from an DRF view you can reference the json body with 'request.data' instead. There shouldn't be a need to load it from request.body.